# How to build a fully secure login: do I need SSL?

Tags: node.js, firebase, security, ssl, heroku

### context

I'm building a project to better understand login/security, and SSL is really tripping me up.
So far I have a front end (vue.js), an API (node/express), and a DB (postgreSQL).

This is the general auth flow:

- When a user logs in they send an email and password (via Axios) to the API.
- The API queries the database for a matching username and then using bcrypt.compare it checks the password that is hashed in the database.
- If this is successful, the API signs a JWT and sends it to the client.
- The client then saves the JWT in local storage and is used for future queries.

### question(s)

So far I think that all of the above is the best practice EXCEPT for the first step. From the reading, I've done so far the client needs SSL to securely send a password to the API. Is this the case? Does my server also need to be SSL or just the client/host?

I'm ultimately going to try to use firebase hosting (which is automatically SSL) for the frontend, and heroku for the API and database. If there are more secure options I'm open to suggestions.

Also, in general, I'm new to all of this security stuff - If I'm missing anything or if something else isn't secure, I would love the advice!

Comment: Since, your backend is going to be hosted by firebase, you would use SSL from between client and server anyways.. firebase may provision an SSL cert for you automatically. So client and app server communication is secured. Now, you need to configure TLS between your app server and Postgres to secure the second hop of the request.

Answer (score 2):

SSL creates a secure connection between two points. In our scenario between the client, and the server. After some initial negotiation, the client encrypts its messages in a way that only the server can decrypt. And the server does the same with its answers, or its own questions.  By using SSL between these two end points, nobody but the client and server can read the messages.

This is important, since a message sent between client and server is actually seen by many more machines/processes in between. Dozens of other processes can thus see the message, and if the message is not encrypted that means all those processes can know exactly what's in the message. When the client and server communicate over SSL, the other processes still see the messages, but they can't decrypt them.

To your concrete questions: the client opens a secure connection to the server. Both the client and the server need to support this. If you write a custom server, that means you'll need to ensure it has a SSL certificate. A very common place to get these for free these days is [letsencrypt.org](https://letsencrypt.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comment and the link! 

You mentioned that the message sent between client and server is seen by many other machines. Would this also be the case if I were to put my API and DB on separate servers? If so would I need to include SSL (or something else) between the API server and the DB server?

Comment: If your app server and the DB communicate over the public internet, the situation would be the same indeed. If you communicate information there that connection would also need to be secured.